# QGIS - Aggregate geometries without including the current feature

Tags: qgis, expression, aggregate

I'm using this expression:

```
    aggregate(
 layer:= 'Dissolved',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:= to_string(predicted),
 concatenator:=',',
 filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)))
```

to search the attributes of all the neighbours of each entity of the layer "Dissolved".

It would be good if the attributes of the current entity wasn't also included to the result.

For example, if I have the entity "A"(1) surrounded by the entities "B" (1), "C"(3), "D"(1) and E(1); the result will be: 1,1,3,1,1 instead of 1,3,1,1.
I cannot replace the value of A (1) by nothing, because it would delete the other 1.

Maybe there is a way to sort the values to get the value of A in the first position and then remove the number in the first position (but I don't know how to do so).
And of course, the value of "A" is not always in the same position.

Or maybe there is another way ?

As proposed, I tried to filter the result with the "id", to avoid attributes from when same "id" is found.
But there is no result, just empty.

Here is the expression:

```
    aggregate(
 layer:= 'Not_Null_Output2',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:= to_string(predicted),
 concatenator:=',',
 filter:=intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(@parent),2)) AND attribute(@parent,'id') <> "id"

)
```

Comment: You could add an 'and' condition to your filter so that the feature Id or geometry is different from the parent Id or geometry

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I cannot find a way to make it work.  I edited my post.

Comment: Try enclosing the filter value in `''` to make it a string: `'intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(@parent),2)) AND attribute(@parent,\'id\') <> "id"'`. (Don't forget to escape the other single quotes around `id`).

Comment: I have the same empty result ('').

Comment: Maybe instead of "id" I can use the geometry. But this : intersects($geometry, buffer(geometry(@parent),2) AND (geometry(@parent)) <> $geometry) gives me the same result (still empty).

Comment: I also tried with this expression:  array_to_string(overlay_intersects('Not_Null_Output2',"predicted")) which gives better results

Comment: Your original expression works fine for me, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First store the feature id in a variable, so the you can get the value of the current feature in the aggregate.

```
with_variable(
    name:='current_id',
    value:=$id,
    expression:=aggregate(
        layer:='Dissolved',
        aggregate:='concatenate',
        expression:= to_string(predicted),
        concatenator:=',',
        filter:=intersects($geometry, geometry(@parent)) AND $id != @current_id
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

For my issue, I simply resolved it by using this expression :

```
array_to_string(overlay_touches('Not_Null_Output2',"predicted"))
```

I couldn't find a way to resolve the issue discussed in the post.